# How can I get a true iOS browser simulation on Windows?

Tags: ios, flash, webkit, simulator

I'm looking for a way to run a real iOS browser simulation environment on Windows.

All of the simulators I've looked at so far (an online simulator and Adobe Air) emulate WebKit but don't come with the same limitations as MobileSafari on iOS, specifically the inability to play Flash.

For example, if I share a YouTube video to Facebook in one of these simulators, it displays the shared object as a Flash object. In MobileSafari, it uses HTML5 video. This is the sort of thing I'm trying to simulate.

Comment: Quick question.... what language are you developing in? Is it a web app? Or a native app?

Comment: Ahh... makes sense... I was thinking... if it was a native app, wouldn't he have a mac and therefore the iOS simulator... Honestly, I don't know simply because I have a Mac. If you want to test a specific feature quickly, I'd be happy to run it on the iOS simulator or my iPod and report the results....

Comment: thats ok. I'm going to need to run a lot of tests with a view source debugger.

Comment: sorry, then... hope someone has the answer :)

Comment: If the only need is for determining if the HTML5 video is loading, how about running [Safari for Windows](http://www.apple.com/safari/download/) and not installing Flash?

Comment: does Facebook fallback to HTML5 video on Safari for Windows without Flash? That's what I'm mainly concerned about.

Comment: I'd certainly hope so - that's the way the winds are blowing - although I think that order is backwards (HTML5 video with Flash fallback)

Comment: ah, so HTML5 is default? interesting

Comment: Tried disabling flash in Safari, Facebook still tries to load the flash version of the video. :/

Comment: Ok found the example I was actually looking for here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/ under `Attaching Audio and Video Data`, though it doesn't answer the question I posed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't provide a link, but I've seen a video recently of one of the Yahoo/Flicker engineers gave a talk about HTML5ing their website, optimizing for mobile.  He said the only real way to test websites for iOS, is to run it on the iP* hardware.  You don't know how it will react via a real connection, & a website can crash the browser (esp in older iPhones with out of memory errors.)

I'm in the same boat :(  I think I will use a remote browser tester at first, then get the hardware later, or atlest borow a friend's on occasion. eg: http://www.compuware.com/application-performance-management/cross-browser-testing.html
http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/adobe-shadow-remotely-browse-inspect-debug-websites-android-ios/ http://www.mobilexweb.com/emulators

I'm not saying do not test on a fake environment.  But I strongly advise real hardware for final testing.

Comment: np. I'm looking for something a bit different. I basically need to make sure my open graph metatags share the right Youtube video format on iOS.